# Create thumbnail image from video url!

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I'm try to create thumbnail image from video url.
I use AV Foundation Programming Guide.
My project have a button and an imageview. When button pressed so thumbnail image will load on uiimageview. 
my code can't work,it's:

```
- (IBAction) btnClick : (id)sender
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgN62D70VLk"];

    AVURLAsset *myAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:myAsset];

    Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([myAsset duration]);

    CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600);

    NSError *error = nil;

    CMTime actualTime;

    CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

    if (halfWayImage != NULL) {

        NSString *actualTimeString = (NSString *)CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, actualTime);

        NSString *requestedTimeString = (NSString *)CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, midpoint);

        NSLog(@"got halfWayImage: Asked for %@, got %@", requestedTimeString, actualTimeString);

        [actualTimeString release];

        [requestedTimeString release];

        // Do something interesting with the image.

        CGImageRelease(halfWayImage);

    }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [imageGenerator release];

}
```

Help me for this problem,please!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerController` has some method to handle this -

```
thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:

requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes: timeOption:

cancelAllThumbnailImageRequests:
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems in your code:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgN62D70VLk is the URL of a web page, but AVAssets must be video or audio files. Note: YouTube does not advertise the URLs of its video files.
- Your call to [myAsset duration] will block. You should instead use the AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading protocol (see loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys).
- You are using halfwayImage after releasing it.

I would recommend watching the AVFoundation sessions from WWDC 2010, and looking at the session sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late but it will help some other who comes to this question.

Look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272872/1223897) answer for the same problem, Hope will help to other guys.