# Taking thumbnail image from video always returns null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am trying to get the first thumbnail from a video.

I tried the following:

**ONE**

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_moviePath] options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *gen = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
gen.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600);
NSError *error = nil;
CMTime actualTime;

CGImageRef image = [gen copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];
UIImage *thumb = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);
NSLog(@"the error is %@: image is %@: url is %@: ",error,_mainThumbnail,[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_moviePath] );
```

However, my log is:

```
the error is (null): image is (null): 
url is file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/D1293BDC-EA7E-4AC7-AD3C-1BA3548F37D6/tmp/trim.6F0C4631-E5E8-43CD-BF32-9B8F09D4ACF1.MOV:
```

**TWO**

```
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_moviePath] options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;

    CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

    AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
        if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
        }
        _mainThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:im];
        NSLog(@"thumbnails %@ ",_mainThumbnail.image);
    };

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
    generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
    [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

The log thumnails null.

Why is the image null? I looked in other forums, and they suggested to use fileURLWithPath -which I am already using.

I am using ios7

Comment: What is `_mainThumbnail`? Are you sure that is not `nil` (cause it appears to be so)? Why don't you try to log `thumb` directly (in 1st example)?

Comment: In the first one it looks to me like _mainThumbnail is never set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try this method. It takes the first frame of the video at the given URL and returns it as `UIImage`.

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailFromVideoAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];

    //  Get thumbnail at the very start of the video
    CMTime thumbnailTime = [asset duration];
    thumbnailTime.value = 0;

    //  Get image from the video at the given time
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:thumbnailTime actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return thumbnail;
}
```

The method does not check for errors as my code using it is OK with just `nil` returned if anything fails.

---

Edit: Clarification of `CMTime` values

`CMTime` has

- `timescale` - think about this as a FPS (frames per second) of the video (25 FPS -> 1s of the video has 25 video frames)
- `value` - identification of concrete frame. In the code above, this says which frame you want to take thumbnail of.

For calculation of frame at exact time, you have to make this calculation:

```
value = timescale * seconds_to_skip
```

which is the equivalent to

```
"Frame of the video to take" = "FPS" * "Number of seconds to skip"
```

If you want to take for example 1st frame of 2nd second of the video, you want in fact to skip 1st second of the video. So you would use:

```
CMTime thumbnailTime = [asset duration];
thumbnailTime.value = thumbnailTime.timescale * 1;
```

Another look: you want to skip first 1s of the video and than take a thumbnail. I.e. on 25 FPS, you want to skip 25 frames. So `CMTime.value = 25` (skip 25 frames).

Comment: what if I want the second one? shall I try thumbnailTime.value = 1?

Comment: Do you need thumbnail of 2nd second or 2nd frame of the video? Why would you need 2nd frame? The difference between the 1st and 2nd one is about 0.04s @ 25FPS :-) However: CMTime defines video time at which the thumbnail should be taken, not the exact number of frame. And my code uses simple premise that 1st frame is at time 0 ;-) So in order to get specific frame, you would probably have to calculate FPS of the video etc, but that is a different discussion

Comment: I mean the 2nd second . how canI get it?

Comment: Please take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake It covers this topic in more detail than I can give you in comments. Basically, `CMTime` docs says "value/timescale = seconds" ... so if you set `thumbnailTime.value = thumbnailTime.timescale * 1` (where 1 is number second of video you'd like to take thumbnail of), you should have approximately time of 1st frame of 2nd second of the video (time 00h00m01s)

Comment: do you mean  thumbnailTime.value = 1 in order to get the 2nd?

Comment: Have you took a look at the answer I sent you a link to in a previous comment? You have to set thumbnailTime.value = thumbnailTime.timescale in order to get the 1st frame of 2nd second of the video. Exactly as I posted in a previous commend. Please read the discussion to the question I sent you link to. Its explains everything you need to know about this

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you really don't understand this simple multiplication relation of the values, I'm sorry, but I don't see any other way how to explain you as this discussion seems like a wasting of my time. If you really don't understand, just copy&paste the code from answer's edit

Comment: Thanks I understand it now. How can I know what is the FPS of the video? I believe that some are more than 25 e.g. 29 as far as I know the video industry

Comment: `CMTime thumbnailTime = [asset duration]` returns duration of the video as the `CMTime`. It means you get FPS and total frames count (duration) of the video. Then you just reset `value` to your time, keeping the same `timescale` (FPS)

Comment: I checked it again, and the image appears landscape left rotated. what is the reason?

Comment: The reason is probably the orientation in which the video was recorded. Video contains metadata specifying orientation in which it was recorded so the players can handle the video accordingly. That you see the video in Camera Roll always in a proper orientation is just a trick of the controller / player

Comment: I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347800/avassetimagegenerator-provides-images-rotated

Comment: Is it possible to cache this Thumbnail ?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone made the same mistake as I did:

Check out if the `URL` is generated using appropriate method. You shouldn't get counfused for local and web `URL`s of the file.

**In case of local video file, use below code:**

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_moviePath];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:movieURL options:nil];
```

**In case of video file from internet, use below code:**

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_moviePath];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:movieURL options:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5.2 VERSION:**

You can find my original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61725804/5305978), where I took inspiration from [rozochkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587157/5305978).

```
func getCurrentFrame() -> UIImage? {
    guard let player = self.player, let avPlayerAsset = player.currentItem?.asset else {return nil}
    let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: avPlayerAsset)
    assetImageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
    assetImageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
    assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let imageRef = try! assetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: player.currentTime(), actualTime: nil)
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
    return image
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTES:**

*requestedTimeToleranceAfter* and *requestedTimeToleranceBefore* should be set to .zero, because, according to source code, "The actual time of the generated images [...] may differ from the requested time for efficiency".

*appliesPreferredTrackTransform* must be set to **TRUE** (default is FALSE), otherwise you get a bad-rotated frame. With this property set to TRUE you get what you really see in the player.

Comment: Thank you! Was requesting frame at 3.0 seconds and always getting the frame at 0 seconds. These settings solved this issue.
requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero

Answer (score 0):

I successfully use this snippet, to get a screenshot from video:

```
- (UIImage *)currentItemScreenShot
{
    AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)playerItem_.asset;

    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    CGImageRef thumb = [imageGenerator 
    copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1.0)
    actualTime:NULL
    error:NULL];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumb];

    CGImageRelease(thumb);

    [imageGenerator release];

    return image;
}
```

**But** in my case - I am doing it two seconds after video was successfully imported in application. ( It had problems with picture orientation, sometimes returned no image or half image if I did it once video was imported).

Comment: what do you mean by successfully imported?

Comment: Well - In my case I film a video or choose from library, then this video is being imported in application (and saved in application cache directory) - if it is successfully saved - then it is successfully imported. There could something go wrong - video corrupted, or full memory or any other problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** version of the accepted answer @Lukas Kukacka answer:

```
func thumbnailFromVideoAtURL(url: URL) -> UIImage?{

        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

        //  Get thumbnail at the very start of the video
        var thumbnailTime: CMTime = asset.duration
        thumbnailTime.value = 0

        //  Get image from the video at the given time
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true // this rotates the image to the correct position the camera took it in

        do{
            let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: thumbnailTime, actualTime: nil)
            return UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)

        }catch let err as NSError{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }

        return nil
}
```

**Bonus**

Under `let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset`) I added:

```
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
```

I had a problem where I would record in portrait, get the thumbnail image and it would get returned in landscape. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5347872/4833705) solved that problem.